# Post data to Azure Event Hub without additional request headers

Tags: c#, azure, cisco, azure-eventhub

We're using Cisco Meraki dashboard, we have client devices reporting wifi data, this is handled by Meraki.

The only option they've given us is to input a redirection endpoint so we can get the data as it gets reported. There isn't any way of appending additional request headers, so that the dashboard can post data directly to azure event hub.

Is there anyway of posting data directly to event hub, without authorization header?